# How to disable debug output Sony Xperia L

Tags: android, debugging, sony

When debugging application in the output window gets a lot of extra debug information.

`09-10 14:26:17.442 D/scheduleTraversals( 7995): mTraversalScheduled:false
09-10 14:26:17.452 D/scheduleTraversals( 7995): mTraversalScheduled:true
09-10 14:26:17.463 D/performTraversals( 7995): mAdded:true`

This information takes 95% of total output. How to disable it?

Device `Sony Xperia L, Android 4.1.2`. Debugging in Visual studio 2012, Xamarin monodroid plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify tag-based filters for logcat. For example:

```
adb logcat -v time BatteryService:V *:S
```

Would give me verbose logs for the `BatteryService` tag, and silence all other logs. For more info about the filters, run `adb logcat --help`.